# Download file after 10 seconds

Tags: php, url, hyperlink, timer

I have created a download page that has a link to a file, I would like the file to download automatically after 10 seconds but am unsure of how to do this. The link to the file is stored in a cookie and is accessed on the download page and stored in a $file variable.

The link to the file will be similar to this:

https://cloud1.taccess.co.uk/cloud/uploads/eed376ad76d1f74b597aa2e21121f7e6tantami_cloud_file_580a40c1eff3af7484ef592c10bff10047b373cdc5dfd.pptx?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ56YO6753B2RUT2Q&Expires=1477473886&Signature=mF6Zy1Mqo3HM5g%2B4cSePaXF9vM8%3D

This points to the file and includes the required permissions for the file to be downloaded. So in short, I am looking for a way for this link to be opened after 10 seconds so that the file can be downloaded.

Comment: Use JavaScript for this. PHP is less than ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tag is PHP. So I assume you want to add some delay for download, I think this

will help you

```
     $filename = "your filename";
    header("content-type:application/any specific header"); // set the header
     // your content 

sleep(10)  // will add delay for 10 sec

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name"); // will download your file
```

in javascript you could do like this

use heroku api to bring the page

```
<div id="hidden" style="display:none"></div>
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
     // var text = 'your url';
      $.ajaxPrefilter( function (options) {
        if (options.crossDomain && jQuery.support.cors) {
          var http = (window.location.protocol === 'http:' ? 'http:' : 'https:');
          options.url = http + '//cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + options.url;
          //options.url = "http://cors.corsproxy.io/url=" + options.url;
        }
      });

      $.get(
          'https://login.yahoo.com/',  // like yahoo
          function (response) {

          var res = response;
           $('#hidden').append(res);


      });

  });
```

after your page is placed inside hidden div  then you could do something like this

```
setTimeout(function(){
   $('#hidden').show();// or fade, css display however you'd like.
}, 1000);
});
```

Comment: I kind of doubt OP is interested in merely making the HTTP request return 10 seconds slower…

Comment: @deceze, as you said is correct but there is no javascript or jquery tag

Comment: Because OP doesn't know what they want. If they knew they wouldn't be asking…

Comment: The download page will have an advert on it which is why I want the user to wait 10 seconds before the file is downloaded. I will look into a javascript option which was given as an option earlier. Thanks