# all *.mp3 download page for wordpress

Tags: java, php, wordpress, audio, nofollow

I want the audio files on the site to be transferred to the page

> dow.php

,, and after counting 10 seconds, it will start downloading.

**my Current code for direct download :**

```
if(!empty($mp3Link)) { 

 $linkHtml = '<a href="'.$mp3Link.'"rel="nofollow">

   <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-542" src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/dan.jpg" alt="link dow" width="249" height="64">
        </a>';
```

Please help me reach a conclusion.

Comment: I dont know about countdown. but just writing download will download it automatically

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40258550/download-file-after-10-seconds This might help you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download file after 10 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40258550/download-file-after-10-seconds)